# XPath $ and curly braces meaning?

Tags: xml, xpath

I am working on adobe workbench and inside there is use of XPath. In a template I see that the use this format (below) ...

I would like to know what it means starting from I am seeing a forward slash and then the sub-directory of my path and then a backward slash followed by `{$....$}` I know what /process_data/ means but why enclosed in curly braces and dollar signs?

```
\\SERVER1\firstdirectory/firstsubdirectory\{$/process_data/@fileName$}.pdf
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Dollar signs (`$`) and curly braces (`{ }`) are not a part of XPath syntax.

If you're certain you're looking at an XPath, that construct is likely intended to be pre-processed and replaced with a calculated or looked-up value prior to being evaluated as an XPath.  Frankly, however, what you've posted *looks more like a directory/file path than an XPath*.

Perhaps really the `{$ ... $}` notation is meant to allow entry of an XPath (`/process_data/@fileName`, in this case) for the purpose of constructing a *file* path.

Comment: I added a picture where this syntax come from. it is inside a template and you are correct the /process_data/.. is part of an xpath. Still wondering why the need of the $ and { }. this is on the Adobe Workbench part of the AEM 6.3 product

Comment: Clearly the `{$ ... $}` notation must mean to treat its contents as an expression (XPath, in this case) to be evaluated rather than as a string literal.